# Update Stats and Table Count

Tags: sql-server

I have few questions.

1. Is there any way to get the Table Row Count if we are not maintaining historical  data for count.
2. Below is for Update statistics

   - Should we run update statistics in our database for all the tables? The database is highly transactional.
   - How should I calculate the sample size that will suite for all the tables.
     There are some tables which gets reindex, this we will ignore. We have a job, which reorganise some tables.

Now the decision need to be taken what table should we update statistics to:

1. The table which has been reorganised

   Or
2. Table which has its statistics outdated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of rows in a table, assuming the table has a primary key field:

```
SELECT COUNT(PrimaryKeyField) AS NoOfRows FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you SunKnight, but i am not looking for just count of the table. What I am looking is if I have got a employee table , and I am not maintaining any count of rows for the table, how would i get this historical count. eg, on 1 sept 200 row was there. On 3rd 50 rows inserted. 4th 10 rows added.

Comment: Unless your records are time-stamped I don't know of a way. If they are time stamped it is pretty straightforward, but even then you would not get information for any deleted records.